# Check-in times at Manchester airport

Tags: air-travel, uk, international-travel, man, abz

Looking at travelling from MAN to ABZ next summer. Previously when I've done this it has been solely domestic (so 1 hour check-in). Flights at the moment are only really showing via AMS with a reasonably short layover - 50 min or so (not enough time to e.g. exit and do anything sensible). Some times are also available via LHR but much longer. For these flights should I respect the international (2 hour) check-in window or the domestic one?

Comment: ASk your airline. MAN has had some awful queues lately though, especially in terminal 3.

Comment: The UK doesn't have passport control for departing passengers, so there is effectively no difference between a flight to London and a flight to Amsterdam, you need to allow enough time to get through security and to your gate (and for your luggage to do likewise if you're travelling with checked luggage).

Comment: ABZ airport code is coming back as Aberdeen for me... are you really considering flying Manchester -> Amsterdam / London -> Aberdeen??!! The train via Preston is probably going to be better!

Comment: Is there any reason you have to book the flight now? Could you wait until Flybe open up their summer 2017 schedule? From their Facebook page - "Hi John, our full Summer 2017 timetables are due out sometime this month. - Sam" (https://www.facebook.com/Flybe/)

Answer (score 2):

If you must choose such an indirect route then [European](http://www.manchesterairport.co.uk/flight-information/flight-departures/) (2 hours) it is, since you *are* proposing to leave the UK.

However, as mentioned in Comments, it seems there would be more direct, cheaper and quicker options than flying via AMS.

---

As an example for June 30, 2017, [Flybe](https://www.flybe.com/web-app/index.html) offer the following at present, amongst many other options:

[image: Direct]